# Apply any kind of Updates on database immedieately C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this program where I want to create a button base from Products on my database(ProductTbl). I found a way to do that 
 Here's the code:

```
   public void DynamicButton() //Function for retrieving record and creating a button for each product
      {
      string select = "select ProductID,ProductDesc,ProductPrice,ProductPic from ProductTbl" ;
       sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select,sqlConn);
       sda.Fill(dataTable);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ExtendedButton prodBtn = new ExtendedButton(); //with ExtendedButton this time
            prodBtn._itemName = dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();//this asigns the product name to the extended button
            prodBtn._itemID = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i][0]);
            prodBtn._myPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[i][2]);
            prodBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            prodBtn.Click += new EventHandler(OnButtonClick);
            prodBtn.Height = 100;
            prodBtn.Width = 100;
            System.Drawing.Font f1 = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
            prodBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(f1.FontFamily,f1.Size,FontStyle.Bold);
            prodBtn.Text = dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            prodBtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            prodBtn.ForeColor = Color.White;
            prodBtn.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
            toolTip1.Show(prodBtn.Text, prodBtn);
            byte[] image = (byte[])dataTable.Rows[i][3];
            prodBtn.BackgroundImage = imgConverter.byteArrayToImage(image);
            prodBtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;               
            flowPanel.Controls.Add(prodBtn);


        }       
       }
```

//You can see this at codeproject

Now the problem is that whenever i add a product on that table using Stored procedure. I don't know how i can sync updates to the datatable that I use with this one. Any  ideas and suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks sorry for the long post

Comment: My prof suggested Asynchronous Task but that was too hard for me. Or maybe  a proper use of SqlDataAdapter.Update() would be enough but I dont know exactly where to put it. By now the latter is my primary option

Comment: If you hook it all up right, I think you should be able to call `Update` on your adapter; you should be using the same dataadapter and datatable/dataset for both cases, though.

Comment: note that I find it is all a lot easier if you use the dataset designer.

Comment: @Sahuagin, What's the advantage of DataSet to a plain DataTable? I thought it was just a set of Datatables. Thanks for responding btw

Comment: @NoobDeveloper a dataset wraps up all of your related datatables and adapters. you can use the designer to create strongly typed datatables based on queries that you write. if the queries are basic, the designer can auto-generate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries as well. you then use a single datatable as the midway between your program and the DB. you can also add as many different types of custom query as you want and hook them up to the same data table. you can also define relationships between datatables, but I can't remember what the benefit of that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.Net Caching with SqlCacheDependency.
See this page for details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx

Comment: Okay I'll try this one. I'll update you later :) Thanks for responding

Comment: This looks a bit hard to understand so it might take my update a while